# Touchegg Setup issues on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 - Macbookpro 11,1

Tags: gnome, 14.04, multi-touch, macbook-pro, touchegg

The issue: Touchegg only works with terminal open.

Hi, I'm trying to setup touchegg so I emulate Mac OS X multitouch gestures on Ubuntu. From what I've read on the internet, it does work with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, not Unity.

I have managed to install touchegg, edit the `touchegg.conf` file, and run it in terminal (literally typing in `touchegg`) to test the new gestures and it works, but only when terminal is open.

I followed most of the setup directions (that applied since this is for unity in ubuntu 12.10) from this link: http://ineed.coffee/1068/os-x-like-multitouch-gestures-for-macbook-pro-running-ubuntu-12-10/

I got lost in the instructions where you make it so that touchegg starts automatically upon startup. I created a .desktop file accordingly, placed it in the mentioned directory, and it doesn't work. I'm guessing this is why touchegg won't run without terminal. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> it does work with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, not Unity.

In unity, by default, [you won't get 3 and 4 finger gestures](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/FAQ) using touchegg (they are reserved). You can try the workaround in the blog you mention but I can't tell if it still works in Ubuntu 14.04. 1 and 2 finger gestures should still be possible to manage using touchegg.

> only when terminal is open

You have to launch a touchegg daemon. Alternatively to the instructions you followed, in Ubuntu you can add it graphically in the [Startup Applications manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gnome-session-common/) (included in the OS, you don't have to install it). Open it and add the following element:

```
Name: touchegg
Command: /usr/bin/touchegg
Comment: Launch touchegg
```

and restart your session.

To edit your gestures easily, you can use a GUI. The official one is in touchegg's download list and there's also the alternative project Touchégg-GCE mentioned in the site's wiki, although I've had some issues with it: elements disappear from the list when trying to add/modify them.

Comment: Could you possibly clarify where the normal GUI can be found for Touchegg? I'm wondering if it would work any better for me than Touchegg-GCE